# MBSA offline scanning problem with new version of wsusscn2

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have problem with MBSA offline scanning for MS security updates. Problem has started with new version of “wsusscn2.cab” file. 
Up until now, everything working fine, with older version of “wsusscn2.cab”. 
When I started scanning this month I recived an error: “An error occurred while scanning for security updates. (0x80070057)“.
When I was scanning with older version of “wsusscn2.cab” everything passed OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Windows Update Agent (wuauclt.exe). Update file to the latest version 7.2 
Download of new version on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949104

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this twice in the five years I've been using MBSA offline scanning. In both instances, Microsoft messed up the wsusscn2.cab file. My machines run in a very secure environment, so I just waited until the following month, and ran it with the new wsusscn2.cab file.

I only use MBSA offline scanning right before creating an updated disk image. Our next image update doesn't occur until August, so I haven't used the most current wsusscn2.cab file.